# Calculation of capacitance parallel to Bidirectional TVS diode

Tags: capacitor, tvs

How to find the value of suitable capacitor, parallel across the Bidirectional TVS diode? Is there any formula to calculate?

Comment: Why would you need this capacitor?

Comment: Capacitance is dependent on junction size and thus conduction ESR and power rating is directly related to capacitance. This applies to all MOSFETs too for Ciss, Coss vs RdsOn.  This relationship is special in TVS diodes because the geometric ratios are such that they are exceptionally low capacitance * ESR time constant, just as all ultralow caps have a low ESR*C value <<1us.  This is very useful for highspeed logic ESD transient protection with minimal slew rate reduction.

Comment: There are many types and FoM's for ESR*pF ratings #TVS - Diodes 
TVS - Varistors, MOVs 
TVS - Thyristors
TVS - Mixed Technology

Comment: are you after determining the equivelent capaitance for a TVS or after adding an additional capacitance?  Equiv capacitance is in the datasheet (temp vs breakdown voltage equation & then a capacitance vs breakdown voltage graph). If you are after adding an additional capacitance... you are the one that needs to spec that as you know why it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

They are all different but the general rule of thumb is capacitance rises as power handling capability increases for pulse power rating

here comparing one TVS diode to another diode. ( aka ESD diode) 
[image]

[image]
 - where Ppw is the pulse power rating where \$ Ppw= Ippm*Vf= Ippm^2*ESR\$

- ### comparing Ppw / Cr ratios in [Watts/pF] or ESR*C=T time constant in [ps] , which is an indication of reaction time.

I picked two TVS diodes from Panasonic at random with a widely different capabilities. ( by orders of magnitude)  using the 0V capacitance for these 402 SMD's

---

Another relationship shown in Varistor tables is peak current @8/20us (risetime/width) two times ESR * pF

[image]

The power dissipation per pF is in the same range and shown above as 1.8W/pF
in spite of significantly different part fabrication, vendor and size.

- The relationship is due to body size, Rja thermal resistance, chip size and junction capacitance
- I estimated Pd steady power dissipation package thermal rating even though used in pulse protection using the std 8/20us IEC/UL Lightning pulse.
  .

  - this is just a quick estimate for relative figures of merit (FoM), not a rigorous equation

Side note

- you can do the same RdsOn * Ciss =T comparison for MOSFETs easily to compare and understand why several stages of MOSFETs are needed to go from logic level to 1000A due to this ESR * Ciss = T , in order to maintain a max acceptable transition time T, of a half bridge switch.